# How can I set value of a variable to an amount that is more than unsigned long long maximum value in C++?

Tags: c++

I know that The maximum value for a variable of type `unsigned long long` in C++ is:

18,446,744,073,709,551,615

but I don't know that how can I set value of a variable to an amount that is more than 18,446,744,073,709,551,615?

Comment: Use a large integer library if you need exact precision, or a floating point type if you can deal with not being able to represent values exactly.

Comment: Use a big-number /  arbitrary-precision library.

Comment: There is no maximum value for `unsigned long long` in the C++ standard. There is a minimum range that it must support, and implementations are free to provide a larger size. That "maximum" value depends on the compiler that you're using. You're right that it's typically the largest value supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can use `__int128`,the only problem is that you can't use `cin`,`cout` or `printf` but you can write a function like that:

```cpp
//output
inline void write(__int128 x)
{
     if(x<0) putchar('-'),x=-x;
     if(x>9) write(x/10);
     putchar(x%10+'0');
}
//input
inline __int128 read()
{
    __int128 X=0,w=0; char ch=0;
    while(!isdigit(ch)) {w|=ch=='-';ch=getchar();}
    while(isdigit(ch)) X=x*10+(ch-'0'),ch=getchar();
    return w?-X:X;
}
```

Comment: Your compiler might already optimize `x * 10 to x * 8 + x  * 2`. Unless you have a performance problem, better to stay with more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla C++ you can't, however, you can use [Boost's multi-precision library.](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)